# HTML background video adjust to screen size that is responsive

Tags: html, css, video, background, responsive

I have a problem concerning my HTML background video.
I found some articles on Stack Overflow, and added it to my HTML and CSS.
But it does not seem to work, it either will not become responsive or it messes with my other divs and elements.

I have a picture:
[image]
(the container of the video element has background color yellow)

And here is the code:

```
.container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow:  0px 10px 24px 0px rgba(50, 50, 75, 0.49);
   font-size: 0;
   background-color: yellow;
   margin: auto;
   z-index: -1000;
}

.container video {
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;

   width: auto;

   position: absolute;

   height: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see, the video width does not adjust to the screen size. I tried `object-fit` but this will make it not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make your container `height: 0` then apply the aspect ratio of the video as `padding-bottom` on the container. You get the aspect ratio of the video by dividing the height by the width and multiplying by 100 to get a percentage value. Then position your video to take up the entire space in the container.

The video in my example is 320x176. (176 / 320) * 100 = 55%.

```css
* {margin:0;}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 24px 0px rgba(50, 50, 75, 0.49);
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1000;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
}

.container video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" loop autoplay></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
I tried this, but it kept showing the background (yellow) from the container on the left and right.
I played around and this did the  trick that did it for me was giving the video a css rule of object-fit: fill;

Comment: @RicardoHagens does my demo work like you want it? `object-fit` is great but it has very poor browser support.

Comment: Hey Michael, sorry for the late response, thanks for the tip in 2019!
Got the fix I wanted so my attention from StackOverflow was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video to always fill 100% width and 100% height of your container, no matter the ratio, then you should go with `overflow:hidden`, and play with the position top,right,bottom,left attributes if you want to center it.

```
.container .video{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me what i desired for desktop at least:

```
.container{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;

  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow:  0px 10px 24px 0px rgba(50, 50, 75, 0.49);

  margin: auto;

  font-size: 0;
}


.container video{

    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
   position: static;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: fill;

  }
```

for mobile I will give it a different rule, cause now the video changes aspect ratio (which I desired).